# Write to file multi thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, file, file-io

I first tried opening the file in main(), but when my consumer threads attempted to write with fputs or change the file pointer with fseek, I received a segmentation fault.


So I tried opening the file and writing to the file inside the critical section of the thread. This time there was no errors, but the file was not correct. Each character except the last one was a "NUL" symbol.

Ex:

expected: abcdefg

result  : NULNULNULNULNULNULg

Here is my consumer thread:

```
void *OUTthread(void *arg)
{

    FILE *targetFile;
    struct timespec t;
    t.tv_sec = 0;
    t.tv_nsec = rand()%(TEN_MILLIS_IN_NANOS+1);
    nanosleep(&t, NULL);

    BufferItem OUTresult;

    while(TRUE){

        /*** CRITICAL SECTION *************************/
        sem_wait(&full);
        pthread_mutex_lock( &pt_mutex );
        cbRead(&cBuff, &OUTresult);
        printf("From buffer: offset %d char %c\n", OUTresult.offset, OUTresult.data); 
        // The data printed to stdout is correct, so why is it NUL in the file?

        if (!(targetFile = fopen(arg, "w+"))) {
            printf("could not open output file for writing");
        }
        if (fseek(targetFile, OUTresult.offset, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error setting output file position to %u\n",
                    (unsigned int) OUTresult.offset);
            exit(-1);
        }
        if (fputc(OUTresult.data, targetFile) == EOF) {
            fprintf(stderr, "error writing byte %d to output file\n", OUTresult.data);
            exit(-1);
        }
        fclose(targetFile);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &pt_mutex );
        sem_post(&empty); /* signal empty */
        /*** END CRITICAL SECTION ****************************/

        t.tv_sec = 0;
        t.tv_nsec = rand()%(TEN_MILLIS_IN_NANOS+1);
        nanosleep(&t, NULL);

    }

    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

### Edit

The bufferItem

```
typedef  struct {
     char  data ;
     off_t offset ; // Position of the char.
} BufferItem ;
```

Here is the function that reads the oldest item in the circular buffer.

```
void cbRead(CircularBuffer *cb, BufferItem *cbItem) {
    *cbItem = cb->cBuffItems[cb->startInd];
    cb->startInd = (cb->startInd + 1) % cb->size;
}
```

And here is the rest of the circular buffer implementation if required:

```
// Circular buffer
typedef struct {
    int startInd; // Index of first element added to buffer.
    int lastInd; // Index of most recent element added to buffer.
    int size; // Number of elements in circular buffer.
    BufferItem *cBuffItems; // Circular buffer items.
} CircularBuffer;

void addItem(CircularBuffer *cBuff, BufferItem *cbItem) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems[cBuff->lastInd] = *cbItem;
    cBuff->lastInd = ( ((cBuff->lastInd) + 1) % cBuff->size);
    if (cBuff->lastInd == cBuff->startInd)
    {
        cBuff->startInd = (cBuff->startInd + 1) % cBuff->size; // Overwriting full buffer.
    }
}


void initializeBuffer(CircularBuffer *cBuff, int size) {
    cBuff->cBuffItems = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(BufferItem));
    cBuff->size  = size + 1;
    cBuff->startInd = 0;
    cBuff->lastInd   = 0;
}

int cbIsEmpty(CircularBuffer *cb) {
    return cb->lastInd == cb->startInd;
}
```

Comment: Can we see `cbRead` function and `BufferItem` object? Specially the last. How many Threads do you have? I have an hypothesis.

Comment: Ok, you have the answer, no more things needed xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me the problem is opening the file with "w+" mode. w+ discards previous contents. Everytime your consumer opens the file (again) you get a truncated file, then you seek to a position and write a character. This discards all previous data, so last in wins, and explains why you see the character from the last consumer, padded by nulls for each previous "seek"

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Try opening with "r+" and if that call fails, then drop back to "w+" (or just use a single fopen with "a" if you dont need to update previous contents). You can also check for existence first with stat() though that is essentially what fopen("r+") does.